# El usuario excedió el max_user_connections valor actual 15

Tags: mysql

Me aparece el mensaje que indica que se excedió el numero total de conexiones, pero al entrar a phpMyAdmin y ver el numero máximo de conexiones me aparece de la siguiente manera:

[image: Numero total de conexiones.]

Entonces realmente no sé cuál es el problema.

Cuando ejecuto el comando `SHOW PROCESSLIST` aparecen aproximadamente 15 registros, pero por lo que dice `max_connections` debería estar sobrado.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Estás usando conexiones persistentes quizá?

Answer (score 0):

Aunque el parámetro [`max_connections`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), que define el número de conexiones TOTALES permitidas, esté fijado a 1000, el parámetro [`max_user_connections`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) define el número de conexiones máximas de un único usuario.

Si ese parámetro está fijado a 15, un mismo usuario solo podrá establecer 15 conexiones simultáneas.

Para ver el valor que tiene ese parámetro debes usar:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_user_connections'
```

Para modificar ese valor hasta el siguiente reinicio del servidor puedes usar:

```
SET GLOBAL max_user_connections = 1000
```

Para modificarlo de manera permamente debes cambiar el archivo de configuración `my.cnf` y agregar el siguiente parámetro en el apartado `[mysqld]`:

```
[mysqld]
max_user_connections = 1000
```

PD: Considera reducir el número de conexiones máximas que acepta tu servidor MySQL. Es probable que sufras limitaciones de recursos de CPU, memoria y, sobre todo, memoria. Debes empezar calculando el uso de memoria que hará ese número de conexiones. Una formula muy reducida sería: [Uso de memoria = (Nº conexiones x Thread Buffers) + Global Buffers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1235).